# How to show $\Gamma(2s)/\Gamma(s+1/2)$ is log convex?

Tags: gamma-function

I read in a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568814429) (Mathematics by Experiment, 2nd Edition, Example 5.13), that $$f=s \to \log(\Gamma(2s)/\Gamma(s+1/2))$$ is convex function. But the book does not explain it and I cannot see why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show its second derivative which is
$$4\psi'(2s)-\psi'(s+1/2)$$
is positive. Here $\psi$ is the digamma function, and 
$$\psi'(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(s+n)^2}.$$
Therefore
$$4\psi'(2s)-\psi'(s+1/2)
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(s+n/2)^2}
-\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(s+(2m+1)/2)^2}.$$
The second sum is the odd $n$ terms of the first sum...

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Lord Shark's perfectly fine answer, you may consider that by [Legendre's duplication formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html)
$$ \frac{\Gamma(2s)}{\Gamma\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)} = \frac{4^s}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\,\Gamma(s) \tag{1} $$
where $\frac{4^s}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$ is blatantly log-convex and $\Gamma(s)$ is log-convex by [Bohr-Mollerup's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem), or as a consequence of Holder's inequality applied to $\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^s\frac{dx}{x e^x}$. I am assuming $s>0$, of course.

Comment: Oh, unfortunately, the book is trying to prove the duplication formula using Bohr-Mollerup. That's why it claims $\Gamma(s)/\Gamma(s+1/2)$ is log-convex.